# percentage margin left and right not working properly

Tags: html, css, margin, percentage

What I'm trying to accomplish is on mobile I want my header to have a 3% margin on the left and a 3% margin on the right. I guess you can say what I have done has worked but its creating a side scroll bar.

Here is my code. 
\

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,400italic);

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #ECEFF1;
}

.content {
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
}

.btn {
    float: right;
    width: 160px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #4285f4;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1110px) {
    .header {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .content {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 3%;
        margin-right: 3%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="btn"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been dealing with this for quite some time now and can't seem to figure out why the scroll bar is there. I'm sure it's something small and I'm just overlooking it.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing `width: 100%;` to `width: auto;` for `.content` in the media query.

The reason is `100% + 3% + 3% > 100%` total width, whereas `auto` will calculate the available space automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute `box-sizing:border-box;` to your content div and it will fix the problem.

The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include.

Link to w3 box sizing explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp